# How to set a tolerance level for equality constraints

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, constraint, precision-and-accuracy

Given two equality constraints: `x+y==250` and `z+p==65` where `x=190, y=50, z=45, p=15`, I want to specify an error-tolerance level of `e=0.05` below which the first equality should be `TRUE` and above which the second equality be `FALSE`.

```
{x=190, y=50, z=45, p=15};
eq1= x+y==250;   (* e=0.0416 is the percentage change from 250*)
eq2= z+p==65;    (* e=0.0833 is the percentage change from 65*)

(*Mathematica output*)
(*FALSE, FALSE*)

(*I like to receive for given e=0.05*)
(*TRUE, FALSE*)
```

How can I set the error-tolerance level of `e=0.05` for the two constraints?

Any idea?

Comment: Search the site for $EqualTolerance

Comment: @MichaelE2: I can give a specific tolerance level for the system of equations, but my question is about an error-tolerance calculated as percentage change in the equality concerned. As far as I know you can not set the tolerance level to percentage changes because every equation has a different level of percentage change.

Comment: A proper objection to `$EqualTolerance` would be that you do not want to use machine precision floats, but would like something that works on, say, exact input such as shown (except for `e=0.05`).  Otherwise, it does what you desire: ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = MachinePrecision + Log10[0.05]},
 {eq1 = x + y == 250., eq2 = z + p == 65.}
 ]``

Comment: @MichelE2: Thank you very much for this answer. Here, what does  `MachinePrecision+Log10[0.05]` do? I know it generates the output I want, but I did not understand what your code does.

Comment: Why are you asking for equality when you don't want equality?  You seem to want $0.95 \cdot 250 \leq x+y \leq 1.05 \cdot 250$ as your first relation, so why isn't this what you are computing?

Comment: @EricTowers: I want equality but the calculations show that the equality does not hold. Therefore, I want to know how much the equality deviates from the true level. If the deviation is not much relative to the error-tolerance level `e=0.05`, then I will assume that the equality holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[choppedEqual]
SetAttributes[choppedEqual, {HoldFirst, Listable}]
choppedEqual[a_ == b_, c_] := Chop[N@(a - b)/a, c] == 0.
```

***Examples:***

```
choppedEqual[x + y == 250, .05]
```

> True

```
choppedEqual[z + p == 65, .05]
```

> False

```
choppedEqual[{x + y == 250, z + p == 65}, .05]
```

> {True, False}

Comment: Yes, you solved my problem. Thank you so much. Regards..

Comment: @TugrulTemel, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: In real case, I have many equations to be tested. It will be time consuming to enter each equation in the format you use. Is there any other way to format `choppedEqual[x + y, 250, .0416]` automatically, separating  the left `(x+y)` and right `250` sides of each equation?

Comment: @Tugrul, please see the new version.

Comment: In your revised answer, I did not see how you included the error-tolerance level of `e=0.05`, but your answers are correct. I see that you do some calculations that I do not fully understand.

Comment: @Tugrul,  I originally misread e=0.0416 and e=0.0833 as different tolerance levels you wished to apply to `eq1` and `eq2`, respectively. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply and revised answer. It works perfectly. Regards,

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Congruent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Congruent.html).

```
ClearAll[Congruent]
TOL = 0.05;
Congruent[a_, b_] := 
  If[Abs[a - b] > 0, Abs[a - b] / Norm[{a, b}, Infinity] <= TOL, True];
```

[image]

#### Addendum

> your answer does not show how I test these equations with Congruent. Can you show me how I use Congruent?

Please note that lines 37 and 39 on the attached screenshot use `Congruent`.

It can be seen in the linked [function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Congruent.html) that the infix symbol of `Congruent` ("≡") can be entered as "Esc === Esc".

```
x + y ≡ 250    
(* True *)

z + p ≡ 65  
(* False *)
```

Using `Block` we can also make bulk evaluations of many equalities.

```
Block[{Equal = Congruent},
 {x + y == 250, z + p == 65}
]

(* {True, False} *)
```

Comment: You seemed to answer the question, but I did not understand what you propose. I have two specific equations and your answer does not show how I test these equations with `Congruent`. Can you show me how I use `Congruent`?

Comment: @TugrulTemel See the update of my answer.

Comment: Now I understand the code, though it is still not so clear how I enter the constraints to be tested.

Comment: @TugrulTemel You can use `Block[{Equal = Congruent},...]` -- see my answer update.

Answer (score 6):

Some more ways, with the relative error `e = 0.05`:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = MachinePrecision + Log10[e]},
 {x + y == 250., z + p == 65.} (* advantage: equations written in terms of == *)
 ]
(*  {True, False}  *)

{SetPrecision[x + y, -Log10[e]] == SetPrecision[250, -Log10[e]], 
 SetPrecision[z + p, -Log10[e]] == SetPrecision[65, -Log10[e]]}
(*  {True, False}  *)

svn = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[Infinity, {e, 0}];
{svn[{x + y - 250}, {250}] < 1, svn[{z + p - 65}, {65}] < 1}
(*  {True, False}  *)
```

Comment: The first seems to be the obviously correct way to do this, to my eyes at least.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The first option will be my choice because it uses the equations in terms of `==`. What I do not understand is what `MachinePrecision+Log10[e]` imposes as the tolerance level? What kind of number is that?

Comment: @TugrulTemel See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86815/can-someone-please-explain-internalsameqtolerance/86819#86819 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748 for some discussion.  Setting `$EqualTolerance` to `a` causes two numbers to be considered equal if they agree except for the lower-order `a` digits (base 10), which means that machine-precision numbers would be considered equal if the relative error is less than `10^(MachinePrecision - a)`. Hence if it is set to `MachinePrecision - a`, they would be equal if the relative error is less than `10^a`, where `a = Log10[e]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you very much for your explanation and reference for reading.