# stumped by a simple subtraction

Tags: function-construction, numerics

I have been struggling with the following problem all day today and I can't see anymore. I am transferring a badly written program in Mathcad to something I am trying to make sense of in Mathematica:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
kB = 1.38 10^-23;
hp = 6.626 10^-34;
el = 1.6 10^-19;
m0 = 9.1 10^-31;
mefn = 1.081 m0;
mefp = 0.6931 m0;
eps0 = 8.854 10^-12;
eps = 11.9 eps0;
Eg = 1.125;

Tex = Flatten[Import["file1.dat", "Table"]];

T0 = 10.;

Eg0 = 1.1692; \[Alpha]g = 4.9 10^-4; \[Beta] = 655.; mt0 = 0.1905; ml0 = 0.9163; 

Ncn[TT_] := 12. mt0 Eg0 (Eg0 - (\[Alpha]g TT^2)/(TT + \[Beta]))^-1 ml0^(1/2) (6.28 m0 kB TT/hp^2)^(3/2);

dEt0n = {0.06, 0.09, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1765, 0.15, 0.19, 0.22, 0.28, 0.545,
    0.479, 0.39, 0.424, 0.44, 0.456, 0.475, 0.46};
snn = {0.85 10^-19, 3. 10^-20, 13. 10^-20, 2. 10^-19, 4.05 10^-19, 
   14.4 10^-19, 1. 10^-20, 0.04 10^-19, 1. 10^-19, 2. 10^-19, 
   7. 10^-21, 3. 10^-19, 1. 10^-19, 1.1 10^-19, 1. 10^-19, 3.7 10^-19,
    1.5 10^-19};
nt0n = {0. 10^17, 0.5 10^18, 0. 10^17, 0. 10^17, 4. 10^18, 0. 10^18, 
   0. 10^17, 0. 10^18, 0. 10^18, 0. 10^17, 0. 10^17, 1. 10^18, 
   8.3 10^18, 0. 10^17, 6. 10^18, 9. 10^18, 50. 10^17};

intNTN[TT_] := Block[{Eg0, \[Alpha]g, \[Beta], mt0, ml0, xmtrans, HR,xvtn, xNcn1, xmfn, intT, int, int2, test1, test2, test3, test, xNcn2},
Eg0 = 1.1692; \[Alpha]g = 4.9 10^-4; \[Beta] = 655.; mt0 = 0.1905; ml0 = 0.9163; HR = 0.183;
intT = Join[{T0}, TT];
xmtrans = mt0 Eg0 (Eg0 - (\[Alpha]g intT^2)/(intT + \[Beta]))^-1;
xmfn = 6.^(2./3.) (xmtrans^2 ml0)^(1./3.) m0;
xNcn1 = 2. (6.28 xmfn kB intT/hp^2)^(3./2.);
test1 = Table[NumberForm[xNcn1[[i]] - Ncn[intT[[i]]], {12, 23}], {i, 1,Length[intT]}];
test2 = Table[NumberForm[xNcn1[[i]] - xxNcn2[[i]], {12, 23}], {i, 1,Length[intT]}];
test = Table[{test1[[i]], test2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[intT]}];
test
   ];

Eg0 = 1.1692; \[Alpha]g = 
 4.9 10^-4; \[Beta] = 655.; mt0 = 0.1905; ml0 = 0.9163; HR = 0.183;
xintT = Join[{T0}, Tex];
xxmtrans = mt0 Eg0 (Eg0 - (\[Alpha]g xintT^2)/(intT + \[Beta]))^-1;
xxmfn = 6.^(2./3.) (xxmtrans^2 ml0)^(1./3.) m0;
xxNcn2 = 2. (6.28 xxmfn kB xintT/hp^2)^(3./2.);
test4 = Table[NumberForm[xNcn2[[i]] - Ncn[intT[[i]]], {12, 23}], {i, 1,Length[intT]}];
```

The file I import contain the following values (I am not going to post them all!)

file1:

```
10.215
10.496
10.717
10.888
11.032
11.175
11.324
11.481
11.648
11.814
```

The issue I have is that when I evaluate the function `intNTN[TT_]` for `Tex` I get the following result:

```
{{True,3.35544320000000*10^(7),1.66605114330000*10^(23),1.66605114330000*10^(23)},{True,6.71088640000000*10^(7),1.72007374069000*10^(23),1.72007374069000*10^(23)},{True,0.00000000000000,1.79154129094000*10^(23),1.79154129094000*10^(23)},{True,3.35544320000000*10^(7),1.84842658849000*10^(23),1.84842658849000*10^(23)},{True,0.00000000000000,1.89284708678000*10^(23),1.89284708678000*10^(23)},{True,-3.35544320000000*10^(7),1.93052574704000*10^(23),1.93052574704000*10^(23)},{True,0.00000000000000,1.96818708004000*10^(23),1.96818708004000*10^(23)},{True,0.00000000000000,2.00768594222000*10^(23),2.00768594222000*10^(23)},{True,-3.35544320000000*10^(7),2.04958782237000*10^(23),2.04958782237000*10^(23)},{True,6.71088640000000*10^(7),2.09447434551000*10^(23),2.09447434551000*10^(23)}}
```

Which is obviously bonkers! The two numbers in the difference `NumberForm[xNcn[[i]] - Ncn[intT[[i]]], {12, 14}]` are exactly equal! Yet the difference is sometimes not zero by a lot! And sometimes is zero as it should be. I did this to verify if I was transcribing the mathcad functions correctly and if I was obtaining the same values. Now I fear that if I continue for example with `Ncn` I will get some values in the rest of the program, and if I use `xNcn` from inside that Block I will get some other values.

I stumbled upon this monstrosity and I am stumped!

Can anyone shed some light in here please?

Edit: cleaned up the code a bit.
Edit2: more code cleaning!
Edit3: final code cleaning and final test! I promise!

Edit 4: I said 3 was the last one but I have to add this to clarify something:

What I did it to calculate the same expression three ways:

1. I have revorked the function `Ncn[TT]` so it is not a `Block` construction.
2. I have calculated the expression in question in a regular cell.
3. I have calculated the expression in question inside the `intNTN[TT]` `Block`. Also in there I have calculated the following differences for testing:

a) `test1` is the difference between the expression `xNcn1` calculated inside the `Block` construction and the same expression calculated with the function `Ncn`.
b) `test2` is the difference between the expression `xNcn1` as above, and the same value calculated without a function or `Block` construction with variable name `xxNcn2`

The results are completely different! While `test1` is showing the same numerical error as before, `test2` equals exactly to zero for all values! Here is the output:

```
{{-3.35544320000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000},{3.35544320000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000},{0.00000000000000000000000,0.00000000000000000000000},{3.35544320000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000},{-1.34217728000000000000000*10^(8),0.00000000000000000000000},{-6.71088640000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000},{-1.00663296000000000000000*10^(8),0.00000000000000000000000},{-1.00663296000000000000000*10^(8),0.00000000000000000000000},{-6.71088640000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000},{-3.35544320000000000000000*10^(7),0.00000000000000000000000}}
```

P.S.: I posted this bit of code as I have it because this is how this problem arose! I haven't stumbled upon this until now so I have no idea of another simpler example of how to reproduce it like this!
Apologies for the long code!

Comment: You'll get better answers if you do some work to reduce your problem to its essential core. As it is, few people will be inclined to go through all of your code to find the problem.

Comment: The relative error appears to be on the order of $10^{-16}$, so the numbers are not fully equal, but close enough for `==` to consider them equal (see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86815/can-someone-please-explain-internalsameqtolerance) for more details)

Comment: @LukasLang what do you mean `10^-16`? the difference between the numbers is of the order `10^7`. If it was `-16` I would have been very happy! In any case, what can I do to avoid this from happening? Are the numbers I am using too big? Or too small?

Comment: @LukasLang I get what you said about the relative error. But still that's quite a lot of difference to call two numbers equal... And it doesn't happen consistently! For some of the same order, the difference is zero! And the question remains: which version is correct?

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in the machine representation of numbers. Evaluate `$MachinePrecision` and you should get about 15.9546. That means that you can represent about 16 decimal places plus an exponent. If you look at the documentation for `$MachineEpsilon`, it says it "gives the difference between 1.0 and the next-nearest number representable as a machine-precision number." This number is a bout $2.22 \times 10^{-16}$. If you look at the fraction between your difference and the value, such as $3.3554432 \times 10^7 \div 1.72007374069 \times 10^{23} = 1.95076 \times 10^{-16}$, we see that these values of $10^7$ are basically just `$MachineEpsilon` scaled up by $10^{23}$.

I think there are a couple of ways to deal with this:

1. Don't unless you need numbers that are correct to more than 15ish decimal places. The relative error is extremely small and is unlikely to affect much unless you're adding trillions of slightly incorrect numbers or something. If the numbers you were getting from Mathcad were good enough, then the numbers from Mathematica should also be good enough.
2. Sometimes algorithms can be refactored to perform operations in such a way that errors are either less likely to occur or more likely to cancel.
3. Use arbitrary precision. Mathematica has the ability to deal with exact numbers and arbitrary precision numbers. Exact numbers are the slowest typically, but have the benefit of being... well, *exact*. To use exact numbers, don't put a decimal in your value. Note that evaluate `5/9` in Mathematica gives you `5/9`. If you evaluate `5./9` you get 0.5555555555555555 which is technically wrong but is usually good enough. Depending on what you're doing, arbitrary precision can still be reasonably fast and can hold as many decimals as you have spare RAM on your computer. Notice that `$MaxNumber` ($1.605 \times 10^{1355718576299609}$ on my machine) is far larger than `$MaxMachineNumber` ($1.79769 \times 10^{308}$).

To enter arbitrary precision numbers, you use the grave accent (tilde key) like

```
x = 0.45`100
```

Basically, just put  `` `N `` after every number where N is the precision you'd like to have. However, I notice there's a couple of spots that have the number 6.28. If that's meant to be $2\pi$, then it's hardly worth using arbitrary precision unless all of those 6.28's cancel out. $(2\pi - 6.28)/(2\pi) = 0.0005$, so your calculation may already have 0.05% error in it just from that, and this 0.00000000000002% error from using machine precision will hardly matter. There are other numbers such as Planck's constant, the Boltzmann constant, electron mass, and electron charge which differ from their accepted values by more than that 2 parts in $10^{16}$.

**To summarize:** while $10^7$ might seem like a big number, you have to think in relative terms and, relatively, it's quite small. If you'd like to learn more, I suggest looking at this page on [Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html) in the Wolfram Language. There's also this quite an interesting example on the page for [MachineEpsilon](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html) which I've adapted slightly (where *^ means *10^):

```
y = 1.*^23 + {0.3, 0.5, 0.7} $MachineEpsilon 10^23
(* {1.*10^23, 1.*10^23, 1.*10^23} *)
y - 1.*^23
(* {0., 1.67772*10^7, 1.67772*10^7} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I have now learned some more about Mathematica. However your answer raises more qustions for my problem. If you could have a look at my last edit where I am trying to figure out why I get completely different results if I calculate the same thing using three contructions: in a function, in a `Block` or by itself in a regular Cell. Can you help me figure out why the function version is the only one that displays the numerical error?